# JAVA update ArrayList object method not updating

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

I have an interface test class that implements another super-class. In the test class I have a method that is supposed to update an object from an array list; first it's supposed to check if the objects is in the list, if it is, it will delete and add a new object (replace). If it cant find the object it will throw an exception message. Here is the code I have implemented:

```
public class ProductDBImpl implements ProductDB {

// field declarations
ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
@Override
public void updateProduct(Product product) throws ProductNotFoundException 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Iterator<Product> pritr = products.iterator();
    while(pritr.hasNext())
    {
        Product pr = pritr.next();

        if (!pr.getId().equals(product.getId()))
        {

            throw new ProductNotFoundException("Product does no exist");

        }
        pritr.remove();

    }
    products.add(product);

}
```

First off I dont know if this is the correct way to do it. And, when I test it with my test client script, I get an error that reads:

```
Exception in thread "main" productdb.util.AssertionFailedError: should've gotten ProductNotFoundException
```

The code for the test client is as follows:

```
    ipod.setId(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    try {
        productDB.updateProduct(ipod);
        Assert.fail("should've gotten ProductNotFoundException");
    } catch (ProductNotFoundException pnfe) {
        // expecting this
    }
```

Please help me identify my error. Thanks.

**LATEST EDIT**
I updated my code based on the feedback I was getting RE the first item throwing the error:

```
public void updateProduct(Product product) throws ProductNotFoundException 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Iterator<Product> pritr = products.iterator();
        while(pritr.hasNext())
        {
            Product pr = pritr.next();
            System.out.println(pr.getId());
            System.out.println(product.getId());
            if (pr.getId().equals(product.getId()))
            {

                pritr.remove();

            }
            else
            {
                throw new ProductNotFoundException("Product Not Found");
            }

        }
        products.add(product);

    }
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

```
public void updateProduct(Product product) throws ProductNotFoundException 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Iterator<Product> pritr = products.iterator();
    boolean match = true;
    while(pritr.hasNext())
    {
        Product pr = pritr.next();
        if (pr.getId().equals(product.getId()))
        {

            pritr.remove();

        }
        else
        {
            match = false;
        }

    }
    if (match == false)
    {
        new ProductNotFoundException("Product not found");
    }
    else
    {
        products.add(product);
    }


}
```

Comment: You're throwing the exception on the first step of the iteration. What do you think that will happen when the desired element is the second or the last one in the list?

Comment: Just as @LuiggiMendoza mentions -- you need to walk through your code mentally or on paper as your error should seem obvious then.

Comment: So do I have to iterate through the whole list first, then put the exception outside of the while loop? Sorry if questions seem dumb, but I guess i'm still confused and trying to understand.

Comment: That is correct.  But if you are confused by this kind of thing, I suggest that you follow HovercraftFullOfEels' advice.  Use a pencil and paper to "run" your code.  And continue that approach until you have developed the ability to "run" it in your head.

Comment: Your updated code is making the same mistake.  Please follow @HovercraftFullOfEels advice.  You can't program by randomly guessing bug fixes.  You have to **understand** what the code you have written actually does.

Comment: Where's the mistake?

Comment: You're throwing the damn exception on the first iteration of the loop. Again, please work through your code's logic on paper. Walk through it in your mind. Use a boolean, test it **after** the loop ends.

Comment: I really don't see how its throwing it on the first iteration! It starts the loop, checks the next item for equallness on the given ID. IF it matches it removes it, else it throws the exception but then it continues to loop.

Comment: It starts the loop, checks the first item, and if it doesn't match (the first item, mind you), the else clause is entered and your code throws the exception. And that's it -- **the method ends with the exception being thrown**, and the next item can never be checked. Please use a debugger and see for yourself. **Again**,  use a boolean inside the loop, test it after the loop.

Comment: So how do I make it continue checking the rest of the list? Am I supposed to store the items that dont match in a list then if theres anything in that list throw the exception?

Comment: @DeeTee - Dude.  I don't know why you are ignoring our advice.  But trust me, I've been programming for 40+ years, and teaching people to program for many of those years.  If you don't understand what your code says, you >>need<< to hand execute it.  We are not hostile ... just impatient with someone who is ignoring what we are saying.

Comment: Again, you could declare a boolean before the loop, change it in the loop, and test it after the loop. It's quite simple to do.

Comment: @Stephen How do you know I havent already tried that? I am still stuck. That's why Im here.

Comment: Hint: set a flag when you have matched / removed an element, then test that flag to decide whether to throw the exception.

Comment: Or within the loop if a match is found, you could replace within the loop and then return from the method again from within the loop, and then have the code to throw the exception below the loop since that code will only be reached if no match is found.

Comment: *"How do you know I havent already tried that?"* - We don't, but if you had done it properly, then you would have sorted out your problem.  Because that >>is<< a solution.  Again, the "root problem" here is that the code doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Almost -- again, **walk through your code mentally** -- yes, I'm repeating myself -- but you're not doing it! Make the boolean false to begin with, set it to true if match is found, and throw the exception if it remains false.

Comment: Made the boolean false to begin with, set it true in the if (pr.getId().equals(product.getId())) block, outside of the while I set up if (match == false), then throw error. Then finally I said products.add(...). Still doesn't work. Im beginning to think the throwing of the exception may not be the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, walk through your logic. You have this:

```
public void updateProduct(Product product) throws ProductNotFoundException 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Iterator<Product> pritr = products.iterator();
    boolean match = true;
    while(pritr.hasNext())
    {
        Product pr = pritr.next();
        if (pr.getId().equals(product.getId()))
        {

            pritr.remove();

        }
        else
        {
            match = false;
        }

    }
    if (match == false)
    {
        new ProductNotFoundException("Product not found");
    }
    else
    {
        products.add(product);
    }


}
```

which translates to:

```
start method
    set match to true
    while loop
        if product found remove original product
        else match is set to false  // this will always happen one or more times!
    end while loop

    // match is almost guaranteed to be false!
    check match. if false, throw exception
    else if true, add new product
end method
```

Now assume that the data is:

```
No match  
No match  
No match  
match  
No match  
No match
```

And see what happens. With your logic the boolean will end up false when it shouldn't be.

Compare this with data that should throw the exception:

```
No match  
No match  
No match  
No match  
No match  
No match
```

And again see what happens.

What you want:

```
start method
    set match to false
    while loop
        if product found 
             remove original product
             replace with new product
             set match to true
        // no else block needed
    end while loop

    check match. if false, throw exception
    else if true, add new product
end method
```

or

```
start method
    // no need for match variable
    while loop
        if product found 
             remove original product
             replace with new product
             set match to true
             return from method // *****
    end while loop

    // if we reach this line, a match was never found
    throw exception

end method
```

Comment: In the if product found block, I use remove() then add() to 'replace'. Is this correct?

Comment: @dee try it! Also check changes to the answer. Again my goal is to get you to be able to walk through your code in your mind. Nothing is more important than this.

Comment: Maybe you should stop attempting to help people with poor solutions. Apparently all the things you suggested haven't worked.

Comment: I've seen many good solutions and help on this forum. Too bad I didn't get any on this post. Still I'd like to thank everyone else that tried to help me.

Comment: @DeeTee Help is what you make of it.  If you cannot 'pick up the ball & run with it', please do not blame the person/people who went to efforts to assist.

Comment: *"contributing to the forum by doing...."* a great deal for those that *can* pick up the ball and run with it, while helping to clear some of the noise (through edits, close or down votes & comments).  If SO became chock-a-block full of threads like this, it would be a far less useful tool for finding answers.  (Get over it.)

Comment: Uh oh, the enforcer is here.  Well, thanks for joining the post to come try to protect your friend and not contributing to it in a single way, but piling on to the "chock a block" threads. Real useful.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Thanks for all your help. Your solutions, especially the one that worked (the last one) were all correct. I was able to complete my assignment. Sorry for all the rude comments and thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for coming back with the gratifying and uplifting followup. Congrats on your solving your problem. Please let's forget any past unpleasantness and move forward in a positive light.

Answer (score 2):

The `Assert.fail` is executed when no Exception is thrown and this is the case if:

- either the **first** (this seems to be an unwanted error!) element of the list (`products`) has an equal id
- or the list (`products`) is empty

What's the content of the list?

Comment: The contents of the list are objects of type Product.

Comment: @DeeTee - That isn't what he asked.  He wants to know >>what<< objects are in the list, bot their type.

Comment: Okay and *what IDs* do these products have? The result seems to show that one of these products **does** have the *id* **Integer.MAX_VALUE**.

Comment: The IDs are product IDs; integers.

Comment: Yes, of course. But **what** are the specific numbers of these products? 1? 2? 317? -18? ... ? Please list **all** IDs of **all** products within the list!

Comment: The test script first starts by setting the ipod ID to 100. Then, the script sets the ipod ID to  MAX_VALUE and attempts to update that product (the ipod) via the updateProduct() method.

Comment: You do not answer my question! You say, that there are objects/products in the list and I ask you about the ids of the objects within the list and you answer me with the id of the ipod which is .... ? In the list? Not? What other objects with what ids are in the list?

Comment: The ipod is in the list. Prior to the execution of updateProduct() it has an ID of 100. Post execution it has MAX_ID.

Comment: I didn't think that I would get so much hostility by simply posting a question that I need help on. Especially from @Stephen C and Niklas. You don't really need to help if you dont want to, but I'd appreciate it if you avoided all the smart alec comments.

Comment: BTW: I do spend a lot of time with trying to understand what you do, you don't answer to my questions and now I am hostile?

Comment: I think you're adding the ipod to the list. Then you change the id of the ipod (so that the id of the ipod in the list now also has the new id). When you now try to update the id your list finds the ipod with the same id and does not throw the exception.